# S3Client and Quarkus Native App Issueu with Runn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, quarkus

I am trying to create a lambda S3 listener leveraging Lambda as a native image. The point is to get the S3 event and then do some work by pulling the file, etc. To get the file I am using het AWS 2.x S3 client as below

```
S3Client.builder().httpClient().build();
```

This code results in

```
2020-03-12 19:45:06,205 ERROR [io.qua.ama.lam.run.AmazonLambdaRecorder] (Lambda Thread) Failed to run lambda: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load an HTTP implementation from any provider in the chain. You must declare a dependency on an appropriate HTTP implementation or pass in an SdkHttpClient explicitly to the client builder.
```

To resolve this I added the aws apache client and updated the code to do the following:

1. `SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().
               maxConnections(50).
               build()`
2. `S3Client.builder().httpClient(httpClient).build();`
3. I also had to add:
   `[
   ["org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager", 
   "org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl","software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.Wrapped"]
   ]`

After this I am now getting the following stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:200)
at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:120)
at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:104)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.<init>(PKIXValidator.java:86)
... 76 more
```

I am running version 1.2.0 of qurkaus on 19.3.1 of graal. I am building this via Maven and the the provided docker container for Quarkus. I thought the trust store was added by default (in the build command it looks to be accurate) but am I missing something? Is there another way to get this to run without the setting of the HttpService on the S3 client?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/4968), under review at the moment, that introduces AWS S3 extension both JVM & Native. AWS clients are fully Quarkified, meaning configured via `application.properties` and enabled for dependency injection. So stay tuned as it most probably be available in Quarkus 1.5.0